# Running Express.JS on CPanel in Godaddy on a VPS -- not working

Tags: javascript, express, cpanel

I have written a program on Glitch.com and I want to move to a virtual private server on Godaddy.  I have moved my code, but it is not working.

The place that I seem to be jammed up is in this line of code:

```
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
});
```

When I run it through SSH(I have root access) and try to go to "websitelink.com/", Instead of rerouting to views/index.html, it rerouts to `/public_html`. I think this is because in cpanel, the document root in my domain is 'public_html', but i do not want it like that, any way to change it?

Comment: I don't use cpanel and sometimes wish Godaddy didn't exist, my guess is apache or such web server is on port 80, what port are you using for your node app? if its not 80 you need to include it in the url.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I dislike godaddy too :/ alright, thanks. It usually picks a random port and displays it., like 4380. How do i set the port for my node app?